# SAS - Removing zeros from a character

Tags: sql, sas

I have a character column with values that look like the following:

```
PQRS_XY12345678
PQRS_XY23456789
PQRS_XY34567890
PQRS_XY45678901
PQRS_XY005678
PQRS_XY000123456789
PQRS_XY00012340002
```

I would like to just retrieve number from this column without the leading zeros.
I have used `anydigit` function to fetch the number, however the number of zeros vary for diff records, is there any quick way to ignore/remove any number of zeros before a valid number(non zero)

Comment: Do you want the non-leading zero portion of digits returned as a numeric value or a string value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 ways.  One produces a number the other string.

```
45         data _null_;
46            input string:$32.;
47            n = input(substrn(string,anydigit(string)),32.);
48            n2 = substrn(string,anydigit(string));
49            n3 = substrn(n2,verify(n2,'0'));
50            put (_all_)(=);
51            cards;

string=COUN_IN10346597 n=10346597 n2=10346597 n3=10346597
string=COUN_IN10420787 n=10420787 n2=10420787 n3=10420787
string=COUN_IN0009876543 n=9876543 n2=0009876543 n3=9876543
string=COUN_IN000710008976 n=710008976 n2=000710008976 n3=710008976
string=COUN_IN000710009 n=710009 n2=000710009 n3=710009
```